# Permissions: JS file mime type error

Tags: javascript, permissions

I am having an issue with javascript file stored in siteAssets. Some of our users are unable to see the correct view and I was unsure why at first, until I checked `dev tools (f12)` and found this:

[image]

The first error is the issue. The individual can't see the javascript file that creates the tabbed web parts. I believe it has something to do with permissions and the fact that we have two different site set ups:
`/sites/projectSite`    and    `/sites/projectSite/projectSubsite`

the subsite permissions always inherit from the parent, so I should only have to give a user "owner" status (read capability) on the top level site, and they should have read access to siteAssets of the lower level site, correct? Any guesses on how to prevent this.

Comment: You can check the permission by going into the list settings and permissions tab and check individual user permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you that might want to know the solution... I goofed up in saving the Js files. I have 4-5 different sites to manage and the messed up hillbillytabs was trying to pull the script from a different site. I just had to change the 
/site/site1 to /site/site2 and it grabbed the right file

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure the files are checked in and published so all users can view it at the least.

Comment: All javascript files are checked in nonetheless